# Java TextView Onclick() returning expression error

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I am really new to java and I came across the following 2 errors `error: illegal start of expression public void registerClick(View v)` and `error: class, interface, or enum expected }`
I don't understand what I am doing wrong. I have watched extensive tutorials on Youtube and gone to the Android Studio docs but I can not find out what is wrong with my program. I am trying to go from a signup screen to a register screen if a certain text view is clicked. My code is down below.

**Main Activity.java:**

```
package com.example.gooddeed;

import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;




public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Config Stuff
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.hide();

        //end of config stuff
    public void registerClick(View v)
    {
    TextView tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register);

            }



            }
}
```

**Activity Main.Xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="235dp"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_bg" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="62dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="36.7dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="62dp"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_border_rounded_cornwe">
            <!-- INPUT -->
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/email_input"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/username_icon"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_regular"
                android:hint="Email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingLeft="17dp"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_color"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
            <!-- ICON -->
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/username_icon"
                android:layout_width="14.7dp"
                android:layout_height="10.3dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
                android:src="@drawable/email" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <!-- Spacer Button -->
        <!-- Spacer Button -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="14dp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="62dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12.7dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="62dp"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_border_rounded_cornwe">
            <!-- INPUT -->
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password_input"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_regular"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLength="10"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingLeft="17dp"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_color"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
            <!-- ICON -->
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon"
                android:layout_width="14.7dp"
                android:layout_height="10.3dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
                android:src="@drawable/password" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="62dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="18.7dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="62dp"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_fill__rounded_color"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="14dp"
            android:paddingBottom="14dp"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/forgotpassword"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
            android:text="FORGOT PASSWORD?"
            android:textColor="#1566e0"
            android:textSize="10.5sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/register"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
            android:text="Don't have an account? Make one for free!"
            android:textColor="#1566e0"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="registerClick"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="13.7dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>


    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you to everyone that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have registerClick as a separate method inside the activity  because Java does not support directly nested methods

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Config Stuff
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.hide();

        //end of config stuff
    



         }

         public void registerClick(View v) {
             TextView tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register);

            }
    }
```